# C # Mongo DB collection.find() method does not accept filter

Tags: c#, mongodb

These are my entities;

```
class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Adress { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }
    public string AddressDetail { get; set; }

}
```

My insert code to mongo db as below , there is no problem.

```
        const string uri = "mongodb://usermehmet:inno12345@localhost/testDB";
        var client = new MongoClient(uri);
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(new MongoUrl(uri).DatabaseName);

        counter++;

        User user=new User();
        user.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        user.name = counter+"user";
        user.Adress = new List<Address>();

        Address a1=new Address();
        a1.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        a1.AddressName = "Ev";
        a1.AddressDetail = "a sokak b caddesi c no d kat";

        Address a2=new Address();
        a2.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
        a2.AddressName = "İş";
        a2.AddressDetail = "x sokak y caddesi z no f kat";

        user.Adress.Add(a1);
        user.Adress.Add(a2);

        var collection2 = db.GetCollection<User>("Users");
        collection2.Insert(user);
```

But my query operations that I take from mongodb website ([Query an Array for an Element¶](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/)) are creating editor error at `var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();` line.

```
 const string uri = "mongodb://usermehmet:inno12345@localhost/testDB";

        var client = new MongoClient(uri);
        var db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(new MongoUrl(uri).DatabaseName);


        var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("Users");

        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("name", "100user");
        var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Error:

> > cannot convert from MongoDB.Driver.FilterDefinition ConsoleApplication14.User to MongoDB.Driver.IMongoQuery

[image: Error image:]

Comment: It's strange, your code seems ok, maybe the problem is in usings... try to use lambda instead collection.Find(x => x.name == "100user").ToList();

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using an older version of the MongoDB .NET Driver, as evident from the `GetServer()` call. In the old API, the `Find()` function expected an `IMongoQuery` filter definition.

Try to update your MongoDB.Driver NuGet. The latest is v2.5 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: my all driver is v2.5.0 , so is problem may be from getserver() , there is warning that : " GetServer() is obsolete use the new api instead"

Comment: could you please ,may you share find operations by new api

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but try to remove the obsolete call.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem by mongo db new api methods ,problem was GetServer because it is obsolete.

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl("mongodb://usermehmet:inno12345@localhost/testDB"));
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        _database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("testDB");

        var collection=_database.GetCollection<User>("Users");
        var result = collection.Find(x=>x.name=="100user").ToList();
```